# How to find the index of elements in a Pyspark RDD?

Tags: python, apache-spark, indexing, pyspark, rdd

This is my first question. I am coding in Pyspark. I have and RDD:

```
['a,b,c,d,e,f']
```

How do I find the index of the element 'e'?

I tried zipWithIndex but its not giving me any index.

I saw a similar question, but the solution mentioned did not return me the index

```
rdd.zipWithIndex().filter(lambda key,index : key == 'e') \
    .map(lambda key,index : index).collect()
```

I am getting an error.

Please let me know how to find the index.

Based on the solution provided:

I still have a problem. My rdd is in this format:

```
['a,b,c,d,e,f']
```

So when I try :

rdd.zipWithIndex().lookup('e')

I get [ ]

How should I proceed

Thanks

Comment: You need to split the string of your rdd to spearate rows and then only appy zipWithIndex(). That should solve your issue :)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You get an exception because both `map` and `filter` expect function of a single argument:

```py
rdd = sc.parallelize(['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f'])

(rdd
    .zipWithIndex()
    .filter(lambda ki: ki[0] == 'e')
    .map(lambda ki : ki[1]))

# [4]
```

In prehistoric Python versions tuple unpacking would work as well:

```py
(rdd
    .zipWithIndex()
    .filter(lambda (key, index): key == 'e')
    .map(lambda (key, index): index))
```

but I hope you don't use any of these.

Personally I would just use `lookup`

```py
rdd.zipWithIndex().lookup('e')
# [4]
```

Also - please remember that order of values in RDD might not be deterministic.

Comment: Thank you for the help. I still have a problem. My rdd is in this format:

    ['a,b,c,d,e,f']

So when I try : 

 rdd.zipWithIndex().lookup('e')

I get [ ]

How should I proceed

Comment: If you create `RDD` like `sc.parallelize(['a,b,c,d,e,f'])` it is a single element example. I edited the question to show example input.

Comment: Okay Thank you. But I am working on a Dataset, where I have the elements in ['a,b,c,d,e,f']. So should I first split the elements and then do the lookup?